# Delete range of appointments from a 365 Shared Calendar using VSTO VB add-on

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin

I have been trying to bring this piece of code I found here up to date and make it work for my objective but I keep receiving an error where it expects olFolderCalendar to be a variable and it is undefined. Does anyone have any suggestions please?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            DeleteCal_Appts("Test Shared Calendar", "12/8/2020", "0:00:01", "12/9/2020", "23:59:59")
        End Sub
        Sub DeleteCal_Appts(sCalendarName As String, ap_dateStart As String, ap_startTime As String, ap_dateEnd As String, ap_endTime As String)
            Dim objAppointment As AppointmentItem
            Dim objAppointments As Items
            Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
            Dim objRecip As Recipient
            Dim nInc As Integer
            Dim sFilter As VariantType
            Dim dtStartTime As Date, dtEndTime As Date
            dtStartTime = CDate(ap_dateStart & " " & ap_startTime)
            dtEndTime = CDate(ap_dateEnd & " " & ap_endTime)
            Dim myOutApp As Object
            myOutApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
    
            objNameSpace = myOutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            objRecip = objNameSpace.CreateRecipient(sCalendarName)
            objRecip.Resolve()
    
            objAppointments = objNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objNameSpace.CreateRecipient("Owner User"), olFolderCalendar).Items
    
            sFilter = "[Start] > '" & Format(dtStartTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") &
          "' And [Start] < '" & Format(dtEndTime, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
            objAppointments.Sort("[Start]", False)
            MsgBox("Total Items at begin: " & objAppointments.Count)
            objAppointment = objAppointments.Find(sFilter)
            While TypeName(objAppointment) <> "Nothing"
                'If MsgBox(objAppointment.Subject & vbCrLf & "Delete " & objRec.AddressEntry & " item now? ", vbYesNo, "Delete Calendar Item") = vbYes Then
                objAppointment.Delete()
                nInc = nInc + 1
                'End If
                objAppointment = objAppointments.FindNext
            End While
    
            MsgBox("Deleted " & nInc & " calendar items.", vbInformation, "Delete done")
            MsgBox("Total Items at finish: " & objAppointments.Count)
            objAppointment = Nothing
            objAppointments = Nothing
        End Sub
```

Comment: Does its numeric value (9) work?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, it did take that. But I think there are more fundamental problem with this code. I'm getting an activex error on the "myOutApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")" line.

Comment: What is the error? Is either app running with elevated privileges?
You can also always use CreateObejct with Outlook since it is a singleton.

Comment: Good tip, Changing to CreateObject got me there... also changed the dimension of sfilter to an object type.

Comment: It can see the appointments but doesn't delete them. Does that While statement look ok in terms of being able to iterate though the appointments? seems to bypass that completely.

Comment: I'd rather use Restrict() and iterate through the collection backwards (Count down to 1).